# How can I set http proxy by adb shell at android device with username and password and not root

Tags: android, proxy, adb

I see an answser
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_username
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_password
is unuseful.

So how can I set http proxy with auth by adb,or I can set pac proxy with adb